# Basic way to find out relationships and correlations / mediators

Tags: nonparametric, excel, mediation

Currently I am looking for a very basic way to analyze relationships in a data set which contains nominal and ordinal data.

Mainly I want to investigate, whether two groups, defined by a dichotomous variable, differ in regard of the other variables in the data set. Further I would like to identify underlying mediators which might be responsible for the differences.

As an example, I have the dichotomous variable handedness (left vs. right). By a descriptive analysis of frequencies, I found out that the two groups (left- and right-handed) differ on several variables. Left-handed people for example are more likely to take risks (34% vs. 25%). However, this difference could be explained by the fact that men are in general more likely to be left-handed. Thus, the sample of left-handed people consists of a larger proportion of males who are in general also more likely to take risks.

What I came up with is, to calculate z-scores as an indicator of how big the difference between the groups is. Further I would like to calculate correlations between the variables, which have comparably high values, to identify possible underlying mediators. Subsequently, I would like to calculate partial correlations to get the true correlation between the variables, controlling for the possible mediator. Which would be the most suitable methods in this case? Do you have any other ideas?

I know that there are way more suitable methods for this case such as various regression models. However, I am really looking for a basic way which someone without profound statistical knowledge will be able to follow. Further, I do not want to use any statistical software, except for Excel calculations.

Really looking forward to your help!